# C# Help me with some Generic casting awesomeness

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to write a method for coverting a given object to an instance of a given type.  I started with this:

```
private static T TryCast<T>(object o)
{
    return (T) o;
}
```

Going in, I know *that* isn't going to work, but it illustrates the concept.  Now, I'm going to start having problems when I have types that won't cast automatically, like string --> DateTime.  I was trying to use the Convert Class to deal with these cases, but I just get a compile time error instead of a runtime error.  The following code gets the compile error "Cannot cast expression of type 'string' to type 'T'

```
private static T TryCast<T>(object o)
{
    var typeName = typeof (T).FullName;

    switch (typeName)
    {
        case "System.String":
            return (T) Convert.ToString(o);
        default:
            return (T) o;
    }
}
```

I'm also aware of Convert.ChangeType(), but I'm wondering if it will handle edge cases that I would otherwise handle in the above switch, like the stated string --> DateTime that I'd normally just use Convert.ToDateTime for.

```
private static T TryCast<T>(object o)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
}
```

So, what is my best option?  If somebody can give me a workable *approach*, I can take it from there.

Comment: OK, to give a little context, the immediate usage for this method is to dynamically assign properties on an instance of type T from column values in a DataRow object.  I'd pass in a Dictionary<string, string> where Key = property name on the instance and Value = column name on the DatRow.  I already have the reflection written to get the PropertyInfos from the type and set the instance values.  This casting bit is my last piece of the puzzle.  I'd like it to be as reusable as possible, but if limiting your scope to my example makes it easier, so be it.

Comment: I'm aware that the 2nd example above SHOULD generate the compiler error, and why.  I'm just using it to illustrate the approach, thanks.  Not that new :<)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` should handle edge cases; it delegates to `IConvertible`.

To answer the question, the compiler doesn't know that `T` is `string`.
Therefore, it doesn't let you cast between to unrelated types (just like you can't cast `Button` to `TextBox`).

You can work around that by casting to `object` first:

```
return (T)(object)o.ToString();
```

Now, each individual conversion is allowed by the compiler (it's either a direct upcast or a direct downcast), and you know that the whole thing will work because `T` is `String`.

Comment: Why the heck didn't I think of this?  Let's see what everyone else says, but this might well be the accepted answer.